# Getting the product of a list from left to right

Tags: prolog

How do you get the product of a list from left to right?
For example:

```
?- product([1,2,3,4], P).
P = [1, 2, 6, 24] .
```

I think one way is to overload the functor and use 3 arguments:

`product([H|T], Lst) :- product(T, H, Lst).`

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like a list copy, just multiplying by last element handled. Let's start from 1 for the leftmost element:

```
product(L, P) :-
    product(L, 1, P).

product([X|Xs], A, [Y|Ys]) :-
    Y is X * A,
    product(Xs, Y, Ys).
product([], _, []).
```

if we use library(clpfd):

```
:- [library(clpfd)].

product([X|Xs], A, [Y|Ys]) :-
    Y #= X * A,
    product(Xs, Y, Ys).
product([], _, []).
```

it works (only for integers) 'backward'

```
?- product(L, [1,2,6,24]).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

Comment: i don't really understand how you get the answer, ok you multiply all those numbers but what happens in `product([], _, [])`? how the answer list is being made?

Comment: that's the recursion' base, and 'closes' the list copy. All elements are already computed, then A (stands for Accumulator) is useless.

Comment: i think i got it but its quite hard to come up with this for me

Answer (score 3):

You can use library(lambda) found here : http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl
Quite unreadable :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).


product(L, R) :-
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^(Y = [] 
             -> Z = [X, [X]]
             ;   Y = [M, Lst],
                 T #= X * M,
                 append(Lst, [T], Lst1),
                 Z = [T, Lst1]),
          L, [], [_, R]).
```

Thanks to @Mike_Hartl for his advice, the code is much simple :

```
product([], []).

product([H | T], R) :-
    scanl(\X^Y^Z^( Z #= X * Y), T, H, R).
```

Comment: It would probably be better to define `scanl` as well as Haskell knows it (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:scanl), then it becomes more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably very dirty solution (I am new to Prolog):

```
product([ListHead|ListTail], Answer) :- 
  product_acc(ListTail, [ListHead], Answer).

product_acc([ListHead|ListTail], [AccHead|AccTail], Answer) :-
  Product is ListHead * AccHead,
  append([Product, AccHead], AccTail, TempList),
  product_acc(ListTail, TempList, Answer).

product_acc([], ReversedList, Answer) :- 
  reverse(ReversedList, Answer).
```

- So basically at the beginning we call another predicate which has
  extra "variable" Acc which is accumulator list.
- So we take out head (first number) from original list and put it in
  to Accumulator list.
- Then we always take head (first number) from original list and
  multiply it with head (first number) from accumulator list.
- Then we have to append our new number which we got by multiplying
  with the head from accumulator and later with the tail
- Then we call same predicate again until original list becomes empty
  and at the end obviously we need to reverse it.

And it seems to work

```
?- product([1,2,3,4], L).
L = [1, 2, 6, 24].

?- product([5], L).
L = [5].

?- product([5,4,3], L).
L = [5, 20, 60].
```

Sorry if my explanation is not very clear. Feel free to comment.

Comment: Nice effort (+1). But try to keep the code as simple as possible. It's usually the most rewarding path, regardless the language used. Even more in Prolog.